# Wrapping overloaded functions in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm having some issues with figuring out how to properly wrap a function that may have several return types based on entry parameters in Typescript.

Let's say I want to have a function which, when given `VariantEnum .a` as parameter, will return `ReturnA` and when given `VariantEnum.b` will return `ReturnB`.

Given the following implementation for `sampleFunction`:

```js
enum VariantEnum { a, b }

type ReturnA = string
type ReturnB = number

type VariantReturnMap<V> = 
  V extends VariantEnum.a ? ReturnA :
  V extends VariantEnum.b ? ReturnB : 
  undefined

declare function sampleFunction<V extends VariantEnum>(variant: V): VariantReturnMap<V>
```

It works when calling the function directly:

```js
sampleFunction(VariantEnum.a) // return type is ReturnA, as expected
```

But not when calling it using a wrapper, unless I re-declare everything again:

```
function wrapperFunction(variant: VariantEnum) {
  // something else

  return sampleFunction(variant) // return type is `(ReturnA | ReturnB)`, since we don't know which variant we have yet
}

wrapperFunction(VariantEnum.a) // return type is still `(ReturnA | ReturnB)`

sampleFunction(VariantEnum.a) // return type is still ReturnA, as expected
```

From what I can tell, TS should have enough information to infer that given the wrapper returns the original function, it should have the same return type. However, it always returns the union type instead.

Is there any alternative to make it infer the correct type instead of having to declare it again?

(The same problem still happens when overloading the function with a different method, such as individual declarations for `ReturnA` and `ReturnB`)

Comment: Enums definitions don't use `=`, it's just `enum X { ... }`.

Comment: Fixing the above quip, in [this](https://tsplay.dev/WkKXJW) playground, I get `string | number` instead of `string`. Also, I get another type error where you call the sample function in the wrapper. I cannot reproduce what you have, so I cannot accurately answer the question.

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyXyKm) what you meant? If so, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73721872/edit) the examples in the question and correct them.

Comment: Thanks @caTS, that's exactly what I mean; sorry, was trying to abstract the code as much as possible from my codebase and ended up with some mistakes. Just edited it to make it look like the playground. Also removed the `undefined` since it's not important for my specific implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Wrappers must have the same signature:

```
function wrapperFunction<V extends VariantEnum>(variant?: V) {
  return sampleFunction(variant);
}
```

As far as TS is concerned, `variant` in the wrapper is of type `VariantEnum`, even if you give it `VariantEnum.a` specifically.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/W4n0eN)